# How do I pass multiple params in config.route.js using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass multiple params in my config.route.js file. Passing one param works fine, but I am unable to pass two. The second is optional by the way. Any ideas? This is what I have so far...

```
function getRoutes() {
    return [{
        {
            url: '/main/:containerId',
            config: {
                title: 'main',
                templateUrl: 'app/main/edit.html',
                params: 'containerId',
            }
        }, {
            url: '/main/:containerId/:planId',
            config: {
                title: 'main',
                templateUrl: 'app/main/edit.html',
                params: {
                    containerId: 'containerId',
                    planId:'planId'
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional parameters should be denoted with a ?

example

```
url: '/main/:containerId/:planId?'
```

This fiddle might help you gain more knowledge about optional parameters.

http://jsfiddle.net/p3QaK/14/

In the .otherwise({redirectTo: '/0/'}), the ending / is important and should not be left out. You should try changing it to '/0/3' and you'll see the parameter passed, else only first parameter is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate things when you can use the [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24routeParams) service?

You can skip explicitly defining params in your config.route.js file and simply inject the service into your controller.  With it, you can then access the params within your controller.